# modifiy one element of namedtuple of list

Tags: python, namedtuple, pymupdf

I have written script to extract some information from pdf file.
Each page is read as blocks.
if **[V2G** has been found, then it will saved it as well as the title ,subtitle and the bulleted list.

My code:

```
data = []
req = namedtuple('Req', 'a b c d e f')
    
for page in doc:
   dic = page.get_text("dict")
   blocks = dic['blocks']  # text blocks
   ...
    
   for b in blocks : 
    #title
     if (font1 == 'Cambria-Bold':
         nr = text.partition(" ")
         title = text.partition(" ")[2] 
     #subtitle
    elif font1 == 'Cambria':
         Sub_nr = text.partition(" ")[0] 
         sub_title = text.partition(" ")[2]
    #text
    elif text.startswith('[V2G'):                   
         id = text.replace('[', '')
         txt = text1.strip()
         data.append(req(nr,title,Sub_nr,sub_title, id, txt))
    
    #bulleted list after the text
    elif text.startswith("—"):
         text += "\n" + text
```

the problem is the bulleted list ,because it located in the next block of the text **([V2G)**.
Also not each word begin with **[V2G** has a bulleted list.

So how can I save the text of bulleted list as well as the text from **txt-varibale**  and save it in the namedtuple argument (f)?

then I would like to push it on the same last row of my list?

is it possible to modify just one argument of named tuple and append it to the last element of my list(data) without the another argument?

Result should be:
[image]

Comment: Tuples (named or normal) are immutable, you can't modify an element of it.

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output.  Without the full contect, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: thank you for your commit, I have provide  input and expected output as picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barmar has pointed out in a comment above, (named) tuples are immutable. Why not use a dictionary instead? You could assign new items to this dictionary throughout the loop and update them as well. Appending the dictionary to the `data` list should of course be done as the last step in each iteration.

I am not sure why the bullet point lists have to be treated separately from the other text. It is hard to answer this part of the question without knowing how `text` and `text1` are assigned.

```py
data = []
    
for page in doc:
    dic = page.get_text("dict")
    blocks = dic['blocks']  # text blocks
    ...
    
    for b in blocks : 
        req = {'txt': ""}

        # title
        if font1 == 'Cambria-Bold':
            req['nr'] = text.partition(" ")
            req['title'] = text.partition(" ")[2] 
        
        # subtitle
        elif font1 == 'Cambria':
            req['sub_nr'] = text.partition(" ")[0] 
            req['sub_title'] = text.partition(" ")[2]
    
        # text
        elif text.startswith('[V2G'):                   
            req['id'] = text.replace('[', '')
            req['txt'] = text1.strip()
         
        # bulleted list after the text
        elif text.startswith("—"):
            req['txt'] += ("\n" + text)

        data.append(req)
```

`data` is now a list of dictionaries, which pandas' `DataFrame` class will accept as input.